# Pointing Route 53 to Cloudfront correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an s3 bucket with content in it, which can be browsed if you type in the s3 bucket name (lets call it mydomain.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, and trust me, you can get there). I also have two cloudfront distributions, which you can see below:

[image]

Sorry about the redacting, but I'm not sure what risks I'm putting my client to. As you can see, they are CNAME aliases.

You can also browse these domains and they serve the right content, so I know that the distributions are working.

I have set up two alias records in Route 53, which are pictured below:

[image]

Different docs say different things, but I gather that I create 2 alias records for the cloudfront distribution, one for the domain and one for the www.domain. When I try navigating to the host via either domain url, mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com, I get nothing at all. A ping to the domain says: "Unknown host" Are there any additional steps I need to take? What may be important is that the domain recently came from godaddy, although Amazon maintains that all 14 steps of the transfer have happened, but its been a few days, I think something is definitely wrong.

**EDIT** - So colde pointed me to what was going wrong which is that a whois reveals that the name servers holding the domain record

```
ns66.domaincontrol.com
ns65.domaincontrol.com
```

are from tucows and not amazon at all. So, for all I lknow the cloudfront set up is probably OK, and I need to chase up AWS to find out why the job isn't complete. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: You might have got issues with nameserver. What does your ping to your domains say?

Comment: ping: cannot resolve xxxxxxx.com.au: Unknown host. So I guess, while all 14 step have been done, its still not ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You domain doesn't point to Route 53. A simple whois of your domains says:

`Name Server:                     ns66.domaincontrol.com
Name Server:                     ns65.domaincontrol.com`

It also says your registrar is Tucows, which doesn't seem to align with it being moved to AWS.

Generally, Route 53 nameservers are easily identifiable, here are a the setting from one of my domains:

`Name Server: ns-1408.awsdns-48.org
Name Server: ns-1860.awsdns-40.co.uk
Name Server: ns-93.awsdns-11.com
Name Server: ns-944.awsdns-54.net`

You don't necessarily have to transfer your domain to Route 53, as long as you point the nameservers to the correct ones (you can find them listed as NS records in your zone). You can then still continue to pay your domain through Godaddy or tucows or whatever.

Comment: wow...confirmed. Both Godaddy and Amazon both told my client that it had been moved, but you're right. I just did the whois myself and I get the same. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The problem now is how to get something working. I tried replacing the Amazon NS records with the two listed in the whois and that didn't work either, so I'm really not sure what to do here.

Comment: Interesting, `dig avmaint.com.au A @ns-109.awsdns-13.com` doesn't seem to return valid data. Is the domain still configured in Route 53 with those nameservers and using public hosted zone?

Comment: ah..no, I just changed the NS records to ns66.domaincontrol.com and ns65... in a vain effort to try fixing this.

Comment: Yeah, that won't help. You need to get the domain pointed correctly. And remember, with DNS there is always TTL limitations.

Comment: I have restored the original values